# why is this jQuery not working?

Tags: php, jquery

I'm having this jQuery script thats adding a timer when someone voted he needs to wait 3 minutes

the script is working till the moment I'm getting the remaining time with php

```
$(document).ready(function(){
alert("1");
 function Timer(dur, par, can, cnt) {
var parent = $(par),
    canvas = can ? $(can, parent)[0] : $('.timer', parent)[0],
    seconds = cnt ? $(cnt, parent)[0] : $('.counter', parent)[0],
    sec = dur,
    countdown = sec;    

if (!canvas)
    canvas = $("<canvas>").addClass('timer')
        .attr('width', 100).attr('height', 100).appendTo(parent)[0];

if (!seconds)
    seconds = $("<span>").addClass('counter').appendTo(parent)[0];

var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
ctx.lineWidth = 8;
ctx.strokeStyle = "#528f20";

var startAngle = 0,
    time = 0,
    intv = setInterval(function() {
        var endAngle = (Math.PI * time * 2 / sec);
        ctx.arc(65, 35, 30, startAngle, endAngle, false);
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 200, 200);

        startAngle = endAngle;
        ctx.stroke();

        countdown--;
        if (countdown > 60) {
            seconds.innerHTML = Math.floor(countdown / 60);
            var ss = countdown % 60;
            if (ss < 10) 
                ss = "0" + ss;
            seconds.innerHTML += ":" + ss;
        }
        else {
            seconds.innerHTML = countdown;
        }

        if (++time > sec, countdown == 0) {
            clearInterval(intv);
            $(canvas).remove();
            $(seconds).remove();
            /*$(par).prepend('<img id="theImg" src="http://ivojonkers.com/votify/upvote.png" />');*/
        }
    }, 1000);}



$(".upvote").click(function(){
    alert("2");
    var par = $("<div>").addClass("time").appendTo("#timers");
    Timer(Math.round(180), par);
});
if (<?php echo $wait; ?> > 0) {
var par = $("<div>").addClass("time").appendTo("#timers");
Timer(Math.round(<?php echo $wait; ?>, par); } });
```

so in this part I'm getting the time to wait for the next vote with php and this does not seem to work what's going wrong  ?

```
if (<?php echo $wait; ?> > 0) {
var par = $("<div>").addClass("time").appendTo("#timers");
Timer(Math.round(<?php echo $wait; ?>, par); } });
```

Comment: the jQuery is not working anymore so no errors and when i remove the php part its working again only not getting the time

Comment: `Timer( Math.round(<?php echo $wait; ?>), par); }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should just use a `setTimeout(function(){},(3 * 60 * 1000))` to block the vote functionality.

```
//Block the vote here
setTimeout(function(){/*unblock here*/},(3 * 60 * 1000))
```

Comment: the problem is it need's to work on multiple pages on a refresh this is not working anymore

Comment: With debug console, could you check the generate script and confirm that is not a undefined PHP variable problem?

Comment: if (29 > 0) {
var par = $("<div>").addClass("time").appendTo("#timers");
Timer(Math.round(29, par));
}

so the php is working

Comment: You are a syntax error in function ´Math.round´ : function signature must be ´Math.round(float x)´ : http://www.toutjavascript.com/reference/reference.php?iref=5

Comment: I don't know `Timer` function, but it shouldn't be : Timer(Math.round(29), par); ?

Comment: up here I got this as answer

Replace this:

Timer(Math.round(<?php echo $wait; ?>, par); } });
With:

Timer(Math.round(<?php echo $wait; ?>, par)); } });

Answer (score 0):

Replace this:

```
Timer(Math.round(<?php echo $wait; ?>, par); } });
```

With:

```
Timer(Math.round(<?php echo $wait; ?>, par)); } });
```

;)

Comment: So you have to check $wait (PHP), It must return a INT value ;)